# What's the difference of using `array` vs `StyleSheet.compose()` in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

As per title:
What's the difference of these usages? I can see they all performing the same from UI perspective

```
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import type { JSX } from 'react'

const App = (): JSX.Element => (
  <View>
    <View style={[styles.viewA, styles.viewB]} />
    <View style={StyleSheet.compose(styles.viewA, styles.viewB)} />
  </View>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewA: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    color: '#f00'
  },
  viewB: {
    color: '#0f0'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, using both are same since styles are static. `compose` is useful when styles are dynamic. See the official description below

`Stylsheet.compose(style1, style2)` combines two styles such that `style2` will override any styles in `style1`. If either style is falsy, the other one is returned without allocating an array, saving allocations and maintaining reference equality for PureComponent checks

```
  compose<T: DangerouslyImpreciseStyleProp>(
    style1: ?T,
    style2: ?T,
  ): ?T | $ReadOnlyArray<T> {
    if (style1 != null && style2 != null) {
      return ([style1, style2]: $ReadOnlyArray<T>);
    } else {
      return style1 != null ? style1 : style2;
    }
  },
```

Reference : [react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/dc80b2dcb52fadec6a573a9dd1824393f8c29fdc/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js#L268)

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a time when `StyleSheet.compose` would have been more performant. I think the object returned by `StyleSheet.create` used to go through some type of optimization. In the [commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/a8e3c7f5780516eb0297830632862484ad032c10) where `StyleSheet.create` is changed to be an identity function, they say it will no longer return a number. So before that change occurred, unless there was some magic going on under the hood, I dont think you could merge styles without using that function.

Since the change, `StyleSheet.flatten` and `StyleSheet.compose` seem obsolete. Outside of doing [style preprocessing](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet#setstyleattributepreprocessor), `StyleSheet` as a whole seem obsolete.

I think the reason it remains in use is out of tradition/convention.